# в с# пишет, что индекс находился вне границ массива. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c#

```
private List<string> RSA_Endoce(string s, long e, long n)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    BigInteger bi;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(characters, s[i]);

        bi = new BigInteger(index);
        bi = BigInteger.Pow(bi, (int)e);

        BigInteger n_ = new BigInteger((int)n);

        bi = bi % n_;

        result.Add(bi.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
private string RSA_Dedoce(List<string> input, long d, long n)
{
    string result = "";

    BigInteger bi;

    foreach (string item in input)
    {
        bi = new BigInteger(Convert.ToDouble(item));
        bi = BigInteger.Pow(bi, (int)d);

        BigInteger n_ = new BigInteger((int)n);

        bi = bi % n_;

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(bi.ToString());
        try
        {

            result += characters[index].ToString();// здесь ошибка
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59798/discussion-on-question-by---------).